# Make DraggablePoint Unmoveable on chartplotter (Dynamic Data Display) C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, point, dynamic-data-display

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, including reference Dynamic data display.
I'm creating DraggablePoint in c# code.
The point creating perfect, My problem is how to make the point unmoveable on the map ?
I'm tried to search for property unMoveable or Moveable false but there is no something like this.
My code :

```
    // Creating the new DraggablePoint
    globalPoint = new DraggablePoint(new Point(x1,y1));

    // Set the point position
    globalPoint.Position = new Point(x1,y1);

    // Set the point on the map
    plotter.Children.Add(globalPoint);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a callback that moves the point back to its initial position when it's been moved.

```
Point p = new Point(x1, y1);
var globalPoint = new DraggablePoint(p);

globalPoint.PositionChanged += (s, e) => 
{ 
    globalPoint.Position = p; 
};
```

Comment: exactly what I search for. Thanks dude :)
If you can take a look in my second question I would be verry happy :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440392/make-text-on-segment-on-chartplotter-dynamic-data-display-c-sharp

Comment: and on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442491/brightness-of-chartplotter-dynamic-data-display-c-sharp THANKS